# Postgres multiple joins slow query, how to store default child record

Tags: postgresql, performance, pgadmin, explain

Ive got a small database in Postgres, about 10,000 records storing company customers.
I have a "slow" performing query (about half a second) which is performed very frequently, and my boss wants me to improve it.

First off - my code:

```
select customer_alias.id, customer_alias.name, site.address, phone.phonenumber
from customer_alias
join customer on customer_alias.customer_id = customer.id
left join site on customer.default_site_id = site.id
left join contact_phonenumbers as phone on site.default_phonenumber = phone.id
```

(*Edited `left join customer` to `join customer`*)

What leaps out to me is I am performing a join to `customer` even though i am not selecting anything from that record. I currently have to join it to get the `default_site_id`, a foreign key to the `site` table.

Each customer can have multiple sites, but only one should be displayed in this list (a customer has to be opened to view all sites). So my question is, if i cant optimize the query, is there a different way i can store a default site for a particular customer? The same goes for the default phonenumber

A customer can have many sites, but a site has only one customer( many to one).

---

`EXPLAIN` returns:

```
Hash Join  (cost=522.72..943.76 rows=5018 width=53)
  Hash Cond: (customer.id = customer_alias.customer_id)
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=371.81..698.77 rows=5018 width=32)
        Hash Cond: (site.id = customer.default_site_id)
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=184.91..417.77 rows=5018 width=32)
              Hash Cond: (phone.id = site.default_phonenumber)
              ->  Seq Scan on contact_phonenumbers phone  (cost=0.00..121.70 rows=6970 width=17)
              ->  Hash  (cost=122.18..122.18 rows=5018 width=23)
                    ->  Seq Scan on site  (cost=0.00..122.18 rows=5018 width=23)
        ->  Hash  (cost=124.18..124.18 rows=5018 width=8)
              ->  Seq Scan on customer  (cost=0.00..124.18 rows=5018 width=8)
  ->  Hash  (cost=88.18..88.18 rows=5018 width=29)
        ->  Seq Scan on customer_alias  (cost=0.00..88.18 rows=5018 width=29)
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` returns:

```
Hash Join  (cost=522.72..943.76 rows=5018 width=53) (actual time=12.457..26.655 rows=5018 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (customer.id = customer_alias.customer_id)
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=371.81..698.77 rows=5018 width=32) (actual time=8.589..18.796 rows=5018 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (site.id = customer.default_site_id)
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=184.91..417.77 rows=5018 width=32) (actual time=4.499..11.067 rows=5018 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (phone.id = site.default_phonenumber)
              ->  Seq Scan on contact_phonenumbers phone  (cost=0.00..121.70 rows=6970 width=17) (actual time=0.007..1.581 rows=6970 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=122.18..122.18 rows=5018 width=23) (actual time=4.465..4.465 rows=5018 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 277kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on site  (cost=0.00..122.18 rows=5018 width=23) (actual time=0.007..2.383 rows=5018 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=124.18..124.18 rows=5018 width=8) (actual time=4.072..4.072 rows=5018 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 197kB
              ->  Seq Scan on customer  (cost=0.00..124.18 rows=5018 width=8) (actual time=0.009..2.270 rows=5018 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=88.18..88.18 rows=5018 width=29) (actual time=3.855..3.855 rows=5018 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 309kB
        ->  Seq Scan on customer_alias  (cost=0.00..88.18 rows=5018 width=29) (actual time=0.008..1.664 rows=5018 loops=1)
Total runtime: 27.290 ms"
```

---

Table structures

```
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Table: contacts.customer
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE contacts.customer (
    id                  SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name                integer,   -- Foreign key to contacts.customer_alias
    default_site_id     integer,   -- Foreign key to contacts.site
    -- 12 other fields unrelated to query
    CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
    CONSTRAINT default_site_id FOREIGN KEY (default_site_id)
    REFERENCES contacts.site (id) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
);

-- circular foreign key to customer_alias added later

-- Indexed: id, name, default_site_id (btree)


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Table: contacts.customer_alias
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE contacts.customer_alias (
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL,
    customer_id     integer,
    name            text,
    -- 5 other fields (not used in query)
    CONSTRAINT customer_alias_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
    CONSTRAINT customer_alias_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
         REFERENCES contacts.customer (id) MATCH SIMPLE
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
)
-- indexed: id, customer_id (btree)

-- Customer_alias foreign key
ALTER TABLE contacts.customer
    ADD CONSTRAINT customer_name_fkey FOREIGN KEY (name)
         REFERENCES contacts.customer_alias (id) MATCH SIMPLE
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Table: contacts.site
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE contacts.site (
    id                  SERIAL NOT NULL,
    customer_id         integer,
    address             text,
    default_contact_id  integer,
    default_phonenumber integer,
    -- 9 other unrelated fields
    CONSTRAINT site_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id ),
    CONSTRAINT site_customer_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (customer_id)
         REFERENCES contacts.customer (id) MATCH SIMPLE
         ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
indexed: id, customer_id, default_contact_id, default_phonenumber ( btree)


/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Table: contacts.contact_phonenumbers
 * -------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
CREATE TABLE contacts.contact_phonenumbers (
    id              SERIAL NOT NULL,
    site_id         integer,
    phonenumber     text,
    -- 4 other unrelated fields
    CONSTRAINT contact_phonenumbers_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
-- indexed: id, site_id (btree)
```

If I run the query client side, through ODBC, it takes between 450-500 milliseconds. If I run the query in pgAdmin III, it states the query takes approx 250 milliseconds, although sometimes it takes 60-100ms (which is what I'm aiming for).
I don't currently have SSH access to the server so I can't run it directly.

I only view about 100 of these rows at any time on screen, is it possible to retrieve only the relevant rows? I tried limiting the result for instance `LIMIT 100, OFFSET 2345`, but that performs a fresh search every time.

Thanks very much for the help so far!

Comment: It looks like you need `customer` to get to `site`. 

What does [`EXPLAIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) give you?

Comment: Another question: `LEFT JOIN` will return `NULL` values if no match is found. Is this a requirement of this report?

Comment: Thanks swasheck, yes it needs to display customers that don't have any sites at all (so the user can add them). I'll edit my post to add the `EXPLAIN`

Comment: @berkeleybross It looks like your table isnt indexed (given the sequence scans in the join).

Comment: customer is indexed on id, default_site_id and name : site is indexed on id and default_phone_number : customer_alias is indexed on id and customer_id

Comment: I was also led to believe that postgres will ignore indexes when doing a full table scan/join, or am i mistaken?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you say that it's indexed then that appears to be the case.

Comment: The index is not ignored (see my comment to the answer of @swasheck below). Can you please post the definition of the tables/views used in the query (relevant parts only: PKs and FKs, indexes).

Comment: Please update the EXPLAIN with an EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Differences between planner estimated costs and actual execution can point to the real issue.

Comment: Are there any customer aliases that don't have a customer record?  If not, you can make the first LEFT JOIN a simple  equa- JOIN. (Not clear if that will help speed any.)

Comment: @dbenhur You're right, I've changed the first LEFT JOIN to a JOIN.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You write:

> Each customer can have multiple sites, but only one should be
> displayed in this list.

Yet, your query retrieves all rows. That would be a point to optimize. But you also do not define which `site` is to be picked.

Either way, it does not matter much here. Your `EXPLAIN` shows only 5026 rows for the `site` scan (5018 for the `customer` scan). So hardly any customer actually has more than one site. Did you `ANALYZE` your tables before running `EXPLAIN`?

From the numbers I see in your `EXPLAIN`, **indexes will give you nothing** for this query. Sequential table scans will be the fastest possible way. Half a second is rather slow for 5000 rows, though. Maybe your database needs some [general performance tuning](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization)?

Maybe the query itself is faster, but "half a second" includes network transfer? **EXPLAIN ANALYZE** would tell us more.

If this query is your bottleneck, I would suggest you implement a [**materialized view**](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views).

---

After you provided more information I find that my diagnosis pretty much holds.

The query itself needs 27 ms. Not much of a problem there. "Half a second" was the kind of misunderstanding I had suspected. The slow part is the network transfer (plus ssh encoding / decoding, possibly rendering). You should only retrieve 100 rows, that would **solve most of it**, even if it means to execute the whole query every time.

If you go the route with a materialized view like I proposed you could add a **serial number without gaps** to the table plus index on it - by adding a column `row_number() OVER (<your sort criteria here>) AS mv_id`.

Then you can query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   materialized_view
WHERE  mv_id >= 2700
AND    mv_id <  2800;
```

This will perform *very* fast. `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` cannot compete, that needs to compute the whole table before it can sort and pick 100 rows.

#### pgAdmin3 timing

When you execute a query from the query tool, the message pane shows something like:

```
Total query runtime: 62 ms.
```

And the status line shows the same time. I quote pgAdmin3 help about that:

> The status line will show how long the last query took to complete. If
> a dataset was returned, not only the elapsed time for server execution
> is displayed, but also the time to retrieve the data from the server
> to the Data Output page.

If you want to see the time on the server you need to use SQL `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or the built in `Shift + F7`keyboard shortcut or `Query -> Explain analyze`. Then, at the bottom of the explain output you get something like this:

```
Total runtime: 0.269 ms
```

Answer (score -1):

You only have 10K rows. But conceptually, if you have hundreds of millions of rows and you're developing a time consuming SQL statement - using a `WITH` statement often helps.

```
with ca as
(select customer_alias, name limit 500)
select ca.id, ca.name, site.address, phone.phonenumber
from ca
join customer on ca.customer_id = customer.id
left join site on customer.default_site_id = site.id
left join contact_phonenumbers as phone on site.default_phonenumber = phone.id
```

Especially considering you don't have a where clause, I recommend looking into using a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html).